# jquery selector help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id="my_div".  How can I find a `<select>` by *name* (i.e. `name="my_select"`) assuming that the `<select>` can be at any level underneath the div? I.e. it can be a child, grandchild etc.  Ultimately I need to get the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will search through all [descendants](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) of `#my_div` for `<select>` [elements](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) where the `name` [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `my_select`.

```
var $select = $('#my_div select[name="my_select"]')
```

To get the value of the currently selected option, [use `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
var value = $select.val();
```

Comment: thanks! how can I grab the value of the selected option at this point?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var mySelect = $('#my_div select[name="my_select"]')[0]
```

This will get you the selected option.  Meaning the actual DOM Element

```
alert(mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value);
alert(mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text)
```